# How to call a String returning java method from C JNI?

Tags: c, java-native-interface, jnienv

There are many functions available for calling java from C, However there is no function for call String returning java methods. Can someone please advise how I can call string returning java method from C?

```
    CallBooleanMethod,
    CallBooleanMethodV,
    CallBooleanMethodA,
    CallByteMethod,
    CallByteMethodV,
    CallByteMethodA,
    CallCharMethod,
    CallCharMethodV,
    CallCharMethodA,
    CallShortMethod,
    CallShortMethodV,
    CallShortMethodA,
    CallIntMethod,
    CallIntMethodV,
    CallIntMethodA,
    CallLongMethod,
    CallLongMethodV,
    CallLongMethodA,
    CallFloatMethod,
    CallFloatMethodV,
    CallFloatMethodA,
    CallDoubleMethod,
    CallDoubleMethodV,
    CallDoubleMethodA,
    CallVoidMethod,
    CallVoidMethodV,
    CallVoidMethodA,
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `CallObjectMethod()` and friends. If the JAVA method returns `String`. then the `jobject` returned can be cast to `jstring` and you can use `GetStringChars()` to obtain a `jchar *`

Comment: Note: `GetStringChars()` returns a pointer to an unterminated sequence of UTF-16 code units (jchar), which is excellent if that's what you want. (You can get the jchar count with `GetStringLength`.)